# Granting a Drupal role to all users that have a certain role

Tags: drupal

I need to automatically apply a role, Role X, to all Drupal users that have been granted a separate role, Role Y. In other words, I wish for Role X to be a subset of Role Y. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Won't all of the users with Role Y have Roll X also? Am I correct in assuming that, or will there be users that have Role Y and NOT Role X?

That sort of defeats the purpose of having two different roles since you can just apply permissions to Role Y.

Comment: All those with Role X will have Role Y but not all users that have Role Y will have Role X. Role X is a subset of Role Y.

Concrete example: Role X is toast, Role Y is bread. All toast is bread, but not all bread is toast. I need for all our Toast users to be given the permissions for Toast and for Bread, but not for all our Bread members to be given Toast permissions.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Why can't you give Role Y all of the permissions that Role X has plus whatever extra functionality you want them to have.

Are you trying to use roles to do permissions, or is it to manage something else?

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make a lot of sense. We're in a situation where we (as a membership organization) need to provide content to members but be able to model membership type (student member, full member, lifetime member, etc) using roles. So we have "member" role and "student" role and "lifetime" role and I can ensure that all new signups have both generic "member" role and one that specifies their specific membership type, but up til now that's not been the case, so we currently have people who are "student" but not "member", and that's what I need to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement [`hook_user()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user/6) in a custom module. On the 'insert' and/or 'update' action, you'd check for role Y in the `$account->roles` array. If present, add role X if not already there. This would ensure that your rule gets applied every time a user account gets created and/or changed.

For a bootstrapping/one time operation, take a look at [`user_multiple_role_edit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_multiple_role_edit/6). It lets you add or remove roles for an array of user ids. Alternatively, you could do it directly in the database:

```
INSERT INTO users_roles (uid, rid)
  SELECT uid, [roleX_ID] AS rid FROM users_roles
    WHERE uid IN
      (SELECT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid = [roleY_ID])
    AND uid NOT IN
      (SELECT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid = [roleX_ID])
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Henrik Opel on using hook_user in a custom module would be a good solution to maintain the users and make sure they are up to date all the time.

Normally I wouldn't mind writing SQL or something alike, but in this case, since it's on a production site, I would prefer a different route, since if something can easily go wrong when writing raw SQL, a little typo can cause big troubles. Another good point is that you can run into problems as drupal wont be aware of what raw SQL you run on your database and might get out of sync with some processes, hooks and other processes that's normally run when you do things through the Drupal API.

Instead you can use the drupal user admin interface. I actually think that in this case, it is the **easiest** way to do what you want. Simply filter all users that are students. Click all the users and give them the member role. This is done with a few clicks in no time, and is very secure since Drupal will handle all the SQL for you.

**Updated**
With that many users, I'm surprised that you don't have a custom user and content managing page setup using [views_bulk_operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). Using a few minutes, you can setup a admin page which you can use to preform bulk operations like changing user status, roles, or perform similar tasks for nodes. You can create your own filters using exposed views filters. So with a few clicks you can select all the users with role of student and that isn't member, select them all and add the member roll to them. The advantage doing this is not only that it's quick and safe, but you can create some nice managing pages for your site administrators, content creators etc. You should consider looking into this module.

Comment: This is a good idea, and I would use this solution, but our active member numbers are in the five-digit range and it would take me many days.

Comment: +1 - I totally agree on avoiding direct DB manipulation whenever possible - although less because of the risk of typos (rigorous testing of the change script on a stage instance should prevent those) but mainly because of the implied circumvention of hooks that would get fired when changing things via API calls.

Comment: That's a good point with the hooks, added. I haven't tried any problems due to typos etc, my point was just that it's risky in that sense that only a few chars need to change to mess things up. So a lot of care = testing = time is needed for things like this.

Answer (score -2):

The LDAP module allows you to dynamically assign roles based on DN. I actually had to write my own module that is tailored specifically to our system, otherwise I would be more than happy to share it.

[link text](http://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration)

Comment: I've worked with the LDAP module before, but only for the purpose of user authentication. Would I have to set up a separate authentication system to be able to model sub-roles correctly with the LDAP module? My experience with it is quite limited, I am probably misunderstanding. Please elucidate.

Comment: I don't think LDAP has anything to do with this. The poster would have to set up a separate LDAP server, which seems like all kinds of overkill.